# Java 8 streams: process every possible pair of elements from list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Collection` of elements of an arbitrary class. I want to iterate through the collection and perform some operation using the element and each other element of the collection one-by-one (excluding the element itself). Let it be `List<Integer>` for simplicity:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

With `for` loops it will be:

```
for (Integer i : list) {
    for (Integer j : list) {
        if (!i.equals(j)) System.out.println(i * 2 + j);  //just for example
    }
}
```

The question is **how to do it with the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)?**

That's what I have come to:

```
list.stream().forEach(i ->
    list.stream().forEach(j -> {
        if (!i.equals(j)) System.out.println(i * 2 + j);
    })
);
```

It doesn't look better than nested loop though. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this using the [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) operation:

```
list.stream()
    .flatMap(i -> list.stream().filter(j -> !i.equals(j)).map(j -> i * 2 + j))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This code is creating a Stream of the input list. It flat maps each element of the list with a stream created by the same list, where the current element was filtered out, and each element of this new list is the result of the `i * 2 + j` operation.

All the elements are then printed to the console.

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid object comparisons by mapping to `int` values beforehand, e.g.

```
list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .flatMap(i -> list.stream().filter(j -> j!=i).mapToInt(j -> i*2 + j))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But actually, you are performing conditional operations and equality checks for something that is invariant. As the whole operation relies on the source list not changing its contents in-between, you can simply generate the pairing list indices in the first place:

```
final int end=list.size();
IntStream.range(0, end).flatMap(i ->
    IntStream.concat(IntStream.range(0, i), IntStream.range(i+1, end))
        .map(j -> list.get(i) * 2 + list.get(j)))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

In case you don’t want to calculate a numeric value but create an object for the pairs, it gets a bit more complicated due to the fact that `IntStream` has no `flatMapToObj` operation, so we need a combination of `mapToObj` and `flatMap` (unless we use `boxed`). So constructing a two-length array exemplary looks like:

```
IntStream.range(0, end).mapToObj(i ->
    IntStream.concat(IntStream.range(0, i), IntStream.range(i+1, end))
        .mapToObj(j -> new int[]{ list.get(i), list.get(j)}))
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
    .forEach(a -> System.out.println(a[0]*2+a[1]));
```

Of course, for a list as simple as `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`, we could just use `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5)` in the first place, without dealing with a `List`:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).flatMap(i ->
        IntStream.concat(IntStream.range(1, i), IntStream.rangeClosed(i+1, 5))
        .map(j -> i*2 + j))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```